# New cannot be used in a class that is MustInherit WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have the following code in vb.net. I am using WPF and in the XAML i have a Convertor on the Image. Basically the Image based on the Status level should show a particular Image.

I am having trouble with this syntax. I have an error on "ImageSource" as it says 
"New cannot be used in a class that is MustInherit." I tried removing the New and declaring ImageSource as a String, but the code doesn't return anything into my XAML. What do I need to do?!?

```
    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, _ 
                            ByVal targetType As System.Type, 
                            ByVal parameter As Object, 
                            ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) _ 
        As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim EstadoIndex As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(value.ToString, EstadoIndex) Then
        Select Case EstadoIndex
            Case 1
                Return New ImageSource("/Cogent;component/Images/Green.png")
            Case 2
                Return New ImageSource("/Cogent;component/Images/Red.png")
            Case Else
                Return New ImageSource("/Cogent;component/Images/White.png")
        End Select
    Else
        Return New ImageSource("/Cogent;component/Images/White.png")
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ImageSource` is an abstract class (I guess `MustInherit` this is how you name `abstract` in VB.NET). If you want to return image you can use [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx), which will load image in memory for you, use `new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Cogent;component/Images/Green.png"))`

Also if you need to set it to `Image.Source` - you can just return string, `Image` will load the image.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to OutColdMan and Pondidum,

I had to do a little snopping, but basically both ideas where right on the money. Here is the final code in case anybody is interested!!

```
    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim EstadoIndex As Integer
    Dim bi As New BitmapImage()
    bi.BeginInit()
    'Dim ImageSource As String = "/Cogent;component/Images/White.png"
    If Integer.TryParse(value.ToString, EstadoIndex) Then
        Select Case EstadoIndex
            Case 1
                bi.UriSource = New Uri("/Cogent;component/Images/Green.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                Return bi
                bi.EndInit()
            Case 2
                bi.UriSource = New Uri("/Cogent;component/Images/Red.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                Return bi
                bi.EndInit()
            Case Else
                bi.UriSource = New Uri("/Cogent;component/Images/White.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                Return bi
                bi.EndInit()
        End Select
    Else
        bi.UriSource = New Uri("/Cogent;component/Images/White.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        Return bi
        bi.EndInit()
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You don't need the BeginInit/EndInit stuff. BitmapImage has a [constructor with Uri parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473.aspx).

Comment: And I don't know much about VB, but is it right, or even possible, to have `bi.EndInit()` *after* `Return bi`?

Comment: Hi Clemens, I tried without the EndInit and it didn't work. But From what I had originally posted, I slightly change the code... I added a TryCatch, and at the end added a Finally. I removed all the bi.EndInit from each Case and placed on single line of code in the Finally statement. That worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Checking [ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx) on MSDN shows you need to be using one of its sub-classes, namely a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx)